# How to share secret key for JWT in SSO

Tags: php, http, security, single-sign-on, jwt

I wonder how to share secret key for my JWT between SSO and client? Does the secret key should be randomly generated whenever token is created?

Comment: What is the purpose of sharing the key? If you want the client to verify the JWT, you can use an assymetric key pair and publish the public key in your website. The secret key should generated randomly and be the same for all issued JWT

Comment: I don't know how to pass key from server to client to be sure it won't be hijacked.

Comment: I have detailed the scenario in an answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want the client to verify the JWT, you can use an assymetric key pair (RSA) to issuing your JWT instead of a symmetric key (HMAC), then the token is signed with the private key and verified with the public.

The private key is stored securely in your server, and you provide the public key to the client. There is no security risk in sending the public key to the client or publish it. **Avoid sharing a symmetric key** (same key to sign and verify) **with your client, because then he could create tokens**

The secret key should generated randomly and be the same for all issued JWT

Comment: That's it. Thanks